# Jquery - Find index of select list within page

Tags: jquery, select, indexing

I am trying to get the index of the select list with the class sel when its value is altered. There are many of them within the page.

```
<p>
    <select class="sel">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
        <option>d</option>
    </select>
    => return 0 when changed
</p>
<p>
    <select class="sel">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
        <option>d</option>
    </select>
        => return 1 when changed
</p>
<p>
    <select class="sel">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
        <option>d</option>
    </select>
        => return 2 when changed
</p>
<p>
    <select class="sel">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
        <option>d</option>
    </select>
        => return 3 when changed
</p>

<p id="result"></p>


$(function()
{
   $('.sel').change(function()
   {
       console.log( $(this).index())  //always returns 0  
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the select elements are first child of the `p` elements, if you want to get the index of the changed element in a `select.sel` collection, you should pass the element to the `index` method:

```
$(function()
{
   var $sels = $('.sel').change(function()
   {
       console.log( $sels.index(this) );    
   });
});
```